# Creating a small mouse pendant under windows

Tags: windows

I am not really a windows-programmer, but I am somewhat experienced with scripting languages under linux, like PHP and Python, so I know programming basics.

I would like to write a small sprite/pointer following the mouse movement. The reason is the following:

I am running Linux and I have Windows7 in VirtualBox. Virtualbox has an unfixed bug since a long time, that it is not able to draw the mousepointer on OpenGL viewports, when the mouse is captured. If VBox has mouse integration enabled, it draws the guest's mouse on OpenGL-Views but manipulating the view using mouse (like movements as tilt and pan in 3d-applications) is almost impossible because it moves unpredictable as if one has set the mouse speed to insane high level and it's impossible to steer the view. That happens even when the pointer speed is set really low on the host and the guest. If the mouse is captured, manipulating the view using the mouse is possible - but one does not see a pointer at all.  A search on google shows, that the bug had been reported a few times for some years already, so there are some facing the problem and it's not to be fixed quickly.

tl;dr: It's impossible to use the mouse in many OpenGL-Applications running in VirtualBox.

So I had the idea, that maybe a small pointer like an arrow or a cross would follow the actual system's pointer being always in foreground, indicating where the mouse is when it is not visible due to the VBox bug. So it should be something else than the system's mouse sprite, but an image just drawn always in front.

Can someone please point me to some resources, that could teach me how to write such a small toy using C++ or C#?

Thanks

Comment: If the pointer isn't visible, your pointer "pendant" won't be visible either.

Comment: That's why I don't want to use a mouse sprite

Comment: Then there's no way to do this. If you aren't piggy-backing off of the existing implementation, you'd have to re-write the entire infrastructure that drives the mouse pointer. Sometimes this is implemented in hardware, using video sprites. That's much less common on modern high-powered graphics hardware, I suppose, but it's still a rather non-trivial undertaking. Besides, even once you got all of that going, you'd then have to hope that your new implementation wasn't vulnerable to the same bugs that plague the current implementation and motivated this project in the first place...

Comment: Seems like a better use of your time to track down and submit a patch that fixes the bug in VirtualBox.